# How can I repeat one same letter of a word according to its index in javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I need to make a for loop that repeats the letter "E" in any word written in a prompt by the user.

For example if the person writes "several" it should print "seveeeral" or if the user writes "example" it should print "xampleeeeee"

my Html code is this

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="practice1.js"></script>
    <title>My practice</title>
  </head>
  <body>
 <h2>My example</h2>
 <p id="letterEOutput">Output</p>
 <button onclick="letterE()">Make E's</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is what I have so far with the JS, but I don't know what else to do
I want to use a for loop, and the "x.repeat(y)"

```
function letterE(){
  let many = prompt("Enter your text");
  let letters = "";
  for (let i=0; i<many.length; i++){
    letters += text.charAt(i);
  }
  document.getElementById("letterEOutput").innerHTML = final;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```js
function repeatLetter(entry, letter, times) {
  let text = "";
  let textRepeated = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    textRepeated += letter;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {
    if (entry[i] === letterRepeated) {
      text += textRepeated;
    } else {
      text += entry[i];
    }
  }
  return text;
}

const entry = "Enter your text";
const letterRepeated = "e";
const repeatTimes = 5;

const result = repeatLetter(entry, letterRepeated, repeatTimes);
console.log(result);
```